# Differences between DAO.Recordset,DAO.Recordsets,DAO.Recordset2

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Can anybody explain the differences between `DAO.Recordset`, `DAO.Recordsets`, and `DAO.Recordset2` in MS Access 2007?  Basically recordset is used....Give an example so that its more clear. I found some references from Help Option but I am not clear with its process...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`DAO.Recordset` is an object that represents the records in a base table or the records that result from running a query. Read more about the `DAO.Recordset` object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177501%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

`DAO.Recordset2` is also an object that represents the records in a base table or the records that result from running a query. It has all of the properties and methods of the `DAO.Recordset` object, along with an additional `.ParentRecordset` property to support multi-valued fields. Read more about the `DAO.Recordset2` object [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243540%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

`DAO.Recordsets` is the collection of all open `DAO.Recordset` and `DAO.Recordset2` objects.  Read more about the `DAO.Recordsets` collection [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177475%28v=office.12%29.aspx).