# Is there a limit to how many recordsets you can open in Access using DAO method?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, ms-access-2016

I have noticed that intellisense stops at DAO.Recordset2, is this just a case of not needing to add it to the intellisensor because of how little it would be used, or does VBA limit you specifically to having only 2 open at a single time?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want a Recordset3, Recordset4? No such things. Recordset2 is a type of recordset object used to work with multi-value field.

Comment: That is exactly what I was getting at, even if I didn't know enough to ask it properly lol. I have never had to open more than two at a time before my current project, and when I did I had used Recordset2 for the second regardless of the field types I was working with. Thank you for correcting my assumptions!

Comment: More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924557/differences-between-dao-recordset-dao-recordsets-dao-recordset2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecordSet2 is just a "addtional" "type" of variable, and has ZERO relatonship to the number of reocrdsets you want to open.

So, you are free to do this

```
Dim rst1        As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst2        As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst3        As DAO.Recordset
'.etc. etc. etc.

Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHotels")
Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblFood2")
'. etc. etc. etc...
```

the variable "type" DAO.RecordSet2 was introduced for support of so called multi-value fields (columns) in VBA, and in general is not required.